# Finitely presented homology group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

Given a finitely presented $i$th singular homology group over $\mathbb Z$ of a topological space $X$. If one knows the family of $i$th singular homology groups of $X$ over all possible fields, can one recover the torsion elements of the $i$th integral singular homology? Can one recover the whole $i$th integral singular homology group using these data?

Comment: If one just knows the groups up to isomorphism, then I'm afraid no. The Moore space $M(\mathbb{Z}/4,1)$ (i.e. $H_1=\mathbb{Z}/4, H_{>1}=0$) has the same homology with field coefficients as $\mathbb{R} P^2$.

Comment: Note that if $H_i(X; \mathbb{Z})$ has $p$-torsion, for example, then by the universal coefficients theorem, this affects $H_k(X; \mathbb{F}_p)$ for both $k=i$ and $k=i+1$. So if you fix $i$, just knowing $H_i(-, \mathbb{F})$ for various fields $\mathbb{F}$ would certainly not be enough to reconstruct $H_i(-, \mathbb{Z})$. The counterexample provided by @algori shows further that if you know the groups for all $i$ and all fields $\mathbb{F}$, then this is still not good enough.

Comment: Thank you, but knowing that $H_i(X,\mathbb F_p)$ and $H_{i+1}(X, \mathbb F_p)$ are non-zero will allow to say that there is a p-torsion element in $H_i(X, \mathbb Z)$. Right? In other words, the existence of torsion elements in  $H_i(X, \mathbb Z)$ can be   detected from $H_i(X,\mathbb F_p)$ and $H_{i+1}(X, \mathbb F_p)$. Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: No,  you need to know that they are related by (possibly higher)  Bockstein.

Comment: Sergey: for example, for $X=\mathbb{R} P^2$, both $H_0$ and $H_1$ mod 2 are non-zero, but the integral $H_0$ is $\mathbb{Z}$. On the other hand, if the Bockstein (constructed using $0\to\mathbb{Z}/p\to\mathbb{Z}/p^2\to\mathbb{Z}/p\to 0$) is not identically zero on $H_{i+1}(X,\mathbb{Z}/p)$, then both $H_i(X,\mathbb{Z})$ and $H_{i+1}(X,\mathbb{Z})$ have elements of order $p$; if it is zero however, there may or may not be elements of order $p^2$; to detect those one needs other Bocksteins.

Comment: The space $\bigvee S^i$ has nonzero mod $p$ homology in all dimensions but has no torsion in its integral homology.